Can a FF extension adjust to input delay and minimum reaction time?
This happens to me all the time: I click/tap, time passes, the page finally responds but it starts animating and the click registers on a different element. It's a terrible user experience, it makes you not want to interact. Add in all those sweet transition animations and you're stuck waiting around to see if stuff is going to move on you. On Facebook especially, it's slow and when I go to interact with friend requests, the 'hover' effect brings up more content with more links in it - so I have to move the mouse quickly into the content and interact immediately or wait for stuff to animate again. When that goes wrong it takes me to their page and closes notifications (which I have 20+ every time I reload.) The same kind of thing happens with apps on my phone, but Android is a topic for another day.
(Yes, I need better hardware and fewer FB friends, but this is about a solution that doesn't require me to become a poor shut-in with a next-gen computer just so I can avoid spending time on social media.)
I'm asking if there's a way, just hypothetically, to write a FF extension that triggers on click, takes a snapshot of the layout at that moment, waits for the page to start responding and sends the click through to the intended element. In fact it would be great if it could include reaction time - when I click, I decided to click at least 1/10 of a second earlier, and maybe content was different back then.
So much of the internet is constantly doing work behind the scenes and goes unresponsive for long stretches, and no one seems to care how many unintentional clicks happen. I want to do something about it and I'll learn how to make FF extensions to do so.
